# MiniProfilerEF.Initialize() could not be initialized properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, mvc-mini-profiler

I just started trying out the mvc-mini-profiler in my MVC3 project with EF4.1 and after changing             `MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();` to `MiniProfilerEF.Initialize_EF42();` I'm getting :

> A null was returned after calling the 'GetService' method on a store
>   provider instance of type
>   'MvcMiniProfiler.Data.EFProfiledOdbcProviderFactory'. The store
>   provider might not be functioning correctly.

This method MiniProfilerEF.Initialize(); - was giving me

> The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131047)

So I've replaced dll's with ones I've manually built from the source.

What could be the problem in here ?

Comment: which db are you connecting to? Mark did not implement workarounds for all possible db providers afaik

Comment: regular MSSQL2008. tried all possible dll's and own build. all I get is another kind of error. EF team screwed up really bad this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it helps, the EF team have release a beta preview with a fix for the error

`The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)`

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/28/ef-4-2-release-candidate-available.aspx

You can get it from Nuget using

`PM> Install-Package EntityFramework.Preview`

I just tested it on my build and it fixes the issue meaning you can just call `MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();` as before instead of the new method.

Comment: Installed the preview. Works like charm. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Just an update -- it's not a preview anymore, EF 4.2 is fully released.

Answer (score 0):

Please analyze what version of Entity Framework your application is using
PM> Get-Package

and then  install 
MiniProfiler.EF accordingly

Like in my case I installed 
Install-Package MiniProfiler.EF5